# iwconfig Tw-power value signification

Tags: wireless, ieee-802.11, linux

On embedded Wi-Fi access points relying on hostapd, what is the link between the Tx-power value returned by iwconfig to the actual signal level measured with a spectrum analyzer.

What is not clear to me is the actual meaning of “Tx-power” value. Is this the peak value of the Wi-Fi signal at the centrum of the channel or is it the total power emitted in the selected Wi-Fi channel?

More concretely, can the value returned by iwconfig be used to check if the total emitted RF power is within the allowed RF regulation limits?

Thanks in advance for any help

Best regards

Comment: Questions about configuring consumer-grade equipment are off-topic. You can ask on Super User.

Comment: Well, actually I am not busy with any consumer equipment. I am just trying to set-up an own AP on a standard Linux distribution and I am trying to better understand how the Tx power setting is actually working. But I will also try on Super User, thanks for the suggestion

Comment: What model is the AP?

Comment: I am just using a standard Ubuntu laptop with a 802.11 mini-PCIe module and the ath9k driver. I am using hostapd to run the module in AP mode. It is working fine but now I would like to tune the Tx power. I can do it with the iwconfig command (iwconfig txpower) but I would like to be sure to correctly understand what I am configuring

Comment: Unless stated otherwise, it's total power output.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Tx-Power value is represented in dBm. This is a relative measure, specifically dB relative to a milliWatt. Wikipedia has a good [page on dBm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DBm) that covers the formulas to covert this to [actual power levels](http://www.rapidtables.com/convert/power/mW_to_dBm.htm).

It is my understanding that the Tx-power value provided by iwconfig is a representation of the TX power output of the radio. When it comes to OFDM wireless (most 802.11), the signal strength is relatively uniform across the width of the channel (there isn't really a "peak" at the center frequency).

Where things become unclear for me in Linux is how the antenna gain is accounted for in the configuration (I have never researched this thoroughly, so the answer is probably out there). The adapter can't detect the gain of an antenna, so this should be configured or accounted for somewhere.

As an example if you are legally allowed to transmit at 100mW, iwconfig will typically show a TX power of 20dBm (100mW). However the antenna gain is added to this, so if you have a 3dBi antenna, this would result in a TX power of 23dBm or 200mW. With this 3dBi antenna, the radio TX power should be set to 17dBm to match the allowed 100mW TX power.

If iwconfig assumes a certain type of antenna (possibly based on adapter type?), you may be required to reduce the radio TX power if you use a higher gain antenna.